# Are replica unarmed explosives allowed in hand luggage?

Tags: air-travel, uk, hand-luggage

If not why? A domestic flight within the UK. I have the alternative of going with Virgin Trains if this is going to cause me unnecessary problems.

The item has been bought from [here](http://www.relics.org.uk/dynamite-replica-sticks)

[image]

Comment: Is there any way for you to show that the item is not what it is clearly labeled as?

Comment: @CMaster the receipt maybe?

Comment: You wont be allowed to carry this aboard a plane, replica or not.

Comment: Askers are expected to make a reasonable effort to research their questions before asking here.    A Google search for the exact title of the question, with the word "uk" added, takes me to the gov.uk site linked by Aleks G which answers the question very explicitly.

Comment: You most likely are not allowed to take this on a train, either.  Is it even legal to possess?  I believe that in The Netherlands, possession would be illegal.

Comment: As far as why: because if anybody saw it, it could well create panic and result in you being restrained, the plane diverted, your arrest, and all sorts of other complications. This is also why you can't joke about bombs on a plane/at the airport either. There's no way to tell it's a replica without looking at it more closely, and if someone thinks there's a bomb on the plane, they aren't going to be stopping to look too closely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is clearly not allowed in hand luggage - nor in the checked in luggage.  That is, you are not allowed to transport it by passenger plane at all. [This page from the gov.uk site](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/ammunition) lists what's forbidden in hand luggage, related to weapons and ammunition (emphasis is mine):

> You can’t take any of these items **as hand luggage or in the hold**:
>
> - blasting caps
> - detonators and fuses
> - **imitation explosive devices (including replica or model guns)**
> - mines, grenades, and other explosive military stores
> - fireworks and pyrotechnics
> - smoke canisters
> - smoke cartridges
> - dynamite
> - gunpowder
> - plastic explosives (including black powder and percussion caps)
> - flares
> - hand grenades
> - gun cigarette lighters

I suggest you check the rules for train travel - it may be forbidden there as well.

Comment: Note that even toys which are "obviously" not real guns may be forbidden because the security staff doesn't want to argue borderline cases. If some toy guns get through, people with slightly more realistic toys will try to argue their case. Until the ban on fakes/replicas is weakened and some madman uses one in a hijacking.

Answer (score 3):

If it is detected, you'll certainly have problems. They will ask you why you travel with such a replica. Even if you don't have bad ideas around it, one can certainly state that you could create a panic in the plane if someone sees it. So it will definitely be forbidden. It is the same as holding a fake gun in the street. People aren't supposed to know that it is fake. And even if you tell them it is fake, you could really create a big mess with this so yes it will be forbidden.